# Why am I not able to run this scala program?

Tags: scala, netbeans

I am trying to run the following scala program in net beans. I am not able to run the below. Since I am very new to scala, I am not able to figure out what is going wrong.

```
object HelloWorld {

def main(args:Array[String])
{
  println("hello world");
}
}
```

The information box in the screenshot below says:

> Class "scalaapplication1.HelloWorld" does not have a main method.

**Attaching the screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Please put the *text* of the exception in the post (and perhaps the title). I have -1'ed in hopes to encourage writing better questions. I will remove it if the post is written to actually describe the problem.

Comment: The problem is I am not able run the program in net beans, though I feel the program is correct. Right click --> Debug program and I get the dialog message. That's why I posted the screen shot. I think I have given enough information.

Comment: I agree with pst. The exception text is almost unreadable in your tiny screenshot... It looks like your `Helloworld` type used to be a `class`, then you changed it into an `object`, but did not recompile it... Also, include in your description all the things which you already tried to fix the problem. (Recompiling, cleaning the project, using the command line, etc.) Otherwise it looks like: Got a problem, can't fix it in 2 minutes, passing it straight on to Stackoverflow...

Comment: For the sake of fairness, note that the screenshot is scaled down by StackOverflow. The screenshot graphic is actually larger and very well readable.

Answer (score 3):

I had this, too. First, update your NetBeans. If this doesn't help, try to run it using a Run Configuration, not directly from a popup menu or so. If this still doesn't help, use Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct but the problem which you have described is not reproducible.

Always describe your problem so it can be reproduced.

Here I can suggest that retry from the scratch (which will remove minor mistake, if any) and if problem persists you may describe your problem in elaborate manner with steps you have taken, details of versions you are using etc.

To quick dive into scala and to run your first application (Hello World!); there is a very good step by step tutorial at http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/wiki/Tutorial (Scala-Eclipse IDE).

Comment: Please, do NOT read the Assembla Scala IDE documentation (I'll make sure to remove it this week), use instead the one on the official www.scala-ide.org website: http://scala-ide.org/docs/user/index.html (which also contains a couple of screencasts for "Getting Started with the Scala IDE" and "Features Overview")